# Scrolling of View happens after the position of scroll by touch

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, android-touch-event

I have a customised `View` in an android application which is put inside a `HorizontalScrollView` as shown.

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/feedBackScroller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <com.my.views.OfflineFeedbackView
                android:id="@+id/feedBackView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/session_rec_page_title_bar_height"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/session_rec_page_ctrl_bar_height"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The `OfflineFeedbackView` shows the pitch track of the audio track that I am playing and I scroll this view by calling `scrollTo(newXPos, newYPos)` based on the current time of the playback. The problem that I am facing is that if I scroll the screen by touching and then start the playback, the reference of scrolling seems to get changed on my view and the scrolling takes place from the position to which I scrolled to by touch. I went through the API docs and found that the `scrollTo(newXPos, newYPos)` internally calls `onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)` where `oldl` and `oldt` are the old horizontal and vertical origins respectively. So, what I am interpreting from this is that when I scroll by touching on the screen these origin values get changed. So, I also tried calling `onScrollChanged(newX, newY, 0, 0)` but this just freezes the screen and there is no scroll. Am I doing something wrong? What can be other better ways to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Here problem looks like as you said HorizontalScrollView positions gets changed when you touch.

So one solution may be find the initial top-left position of your scroll view

```
HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView);
int x, y;
x = hsv.getLeft();
y = hsv.getTop();
```

and always scroll your child view relative to these stored x,y positions i.e

```
childView.scrollTo(x+newXPos,y+newYPos);
```